# Generate smallest tree for set of sets

Tags: algorithm, tree, set, language-agnostic, discrete-optimization

Is there any known algorithm for building a tree from set of sets, using a minimum number of nodes?

For example I have the following sets:

```
1. {A, B, C}
2. {B, C}
3. {D, B, A}
4. {C, A}
```

Every set is represented by a path from root to a leaf. They are sets, so the order that the nodes appear in the path is not important.

I need a tree using as few nodes as possible that will represent all of the given sets as paths. One possible solution (not sure if it is minimal) is:

```
       0
     /   \
    C     A
   / \     \
  A   B     B
 / \   \     \
4   B   2     D
    |         |
    1         3
```

where the root node 0 is some empty element.

Comment: Have you thought of any solution yet? Even a brute force approach can help identify an optimal algorithm.

Comment: @kaya3 there is no strong definition on optimal but let say minimum nodes. You are right about balanced, I actually need minimum number of nodes. I edited the question.

Comment: @kiner_shah I think that brute force will be very complex, I need something smarter.

Comment: Minimising the number of nodes smells like it should be NP-complete, but I'll have a think about it.

Comment: My first attempt would be brute force all possibilities. Than think about optimizations (if it is too slow)

Comment: Brute force is not an option. Complexity for brute force will be O(n!*m!) and I have ~50K sets with ~5 elements each.

Comment: Note that a simple greedy algorithm can provide relatively good results. Not totally sure it is really optimum: 1st iteration select element present in most sets -> C. Then select element most present in remainig sets -> A for example. etc. 2nd iteration, branch on the left (under the C): reitere the process. However, here, I assume that branches cannot be further be reconnected. For example, 1st A on the right cannot connect to the B on the left

Comment: Is there a requirement that the tree be binary?

Comment: If the sets were drawn out as a graph, would the graph have to be connected, or can it be disconnected, e.g. 1. A, B, C  2. B, D, E.  3. F, G. These are not connected.

Comment: Do the edges have to be unidirectional? Can the edges be directional? Can the edges have attributes?

Comment: @Damien Already implement it without good results.

Comment: @Dave it must not be binary.

Comment: @GuyCoder It must not be a graph. No cycles are allowed. It must be a tree, and you can use the same node multiple times

Comment: If you think about it, there is no reason you can not start with a graph. Depending upon how you traverse the graph you can end up with a tree. So why put a constraint on yourself. Also you did not answer the question in the comment. Can the final tree be multiple disjoint trees?

Comment: Could you provide a rather simple example where the greedy algorithm doesn't provide a good result?

Comment: @GuyCoder 
If we have the following rules
1. A B
2. B C
3. C D
4. D A
the graph will be the simple cycle, how to generate tree from this graph?
Yes the final tree can be multiple disjoint trees. In the example that I provided there are two trees and I'm using null element as a major root.

Comment: I think this problem is very similar to [trie](https://medium.com/basecs/trying-to-understand-tries-3ec6bede0014) data structure but I am not sure.

Comment: @kiner_shah It is with one major difference, in the trie structure we are putting the words, which means there is an order of the letters. In my case instead words I have sets of letters and they can be in any order, the order is not important.

Comment: @Damien
1. {A,B}
2. {A, C}
3. {B}
4. {C}
If we choose A because of largest number of occurrences, on the first level we will have A, B and C. And that tree will have 10 nodes. But, if we choose just B and C for the first level, we will have tree with 9 nodes.